# How is SMTPJS for sending e-mails with only HTML pages?

Tags: smtp, html-email, email

How feasible is https://smtpjs.com/ to integrate with HTML page to send e-mail via contact form module. I am working with one HTML page and need to integrate the e-mail services.

Seems its free, but any thing need to be include in the page for the courtesy or anything else. guide me